# How to express "I will do it for you" in Korean

Tags: word-choice, translation

I want to say "I will do it for you" in Korean, to express to the listener that I will do a favor to him. I see at least 4 ways to express it:

1. 저는 너를 위해서 할 거예요.
2. 저는 너를 위해서 할 게요.
3. 저는 너를 위해서 해 줄 거예요.
4. 저는 너를 위해서 할 게요.

But I am not sure about the differences between them. How can I express "I will do it for you." in a natural way?

I think this may be quite broad and dependent on the context, so I wish to say this in one of the two following situations:

(a) I take on me to do the favor and want him to know it.

(b) I am happy to help my friend and would do the favor with no problem.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding the difference between (a) and (b) - in a), is it inconvenient to do the favour?

Comment: If the speaker is referring to himself as "저" then he would not refer to the other person as "너".  They are at incompatible levels of respect (I don't know what the grammatical term is). There is no natural sounding generic way to refer to the addressee. If you have to specify the addressee then the reference would become specific, e.g. "아버지를 위해서", "선생님을 위해서", etc.

Comment: You should understand also why the answers are changing "저는" to "제가." You would say "저는" if, for example, other people said they would do something for A, but you, in contrast, would do it for B.

Comment: As for "줄" it is a form of "주다", viz. to give. We may characterize it as an auxiliary (*can*, *must*, etc.), which can combine with any verb to form e.g. "져 주다" (give losing for "지다"), "보내 주다" (give sending, "보내다"), "깨워 주다" (give waking, "깨우다"), "먹어 주다" (give eating, "먹다"), "죽여 주다" (give killing, "죽이다"). "져 주다" implies you could have won, but let the opponent win. "보내 주다" and "깨워 주다" imply that the person released (e.g. a pupil on detention) or roused wanted to be released or roused.

Comment: You might say "내가 먹어 줄게" if that benefited someone somehow, e.g. you were leaving food uneaten after ordering too much and that bothered one of the company as a matter of principle. "죽여 준다" is a common phrase to praise or (ironically) deprecate something. A movie might. 그 영화 죽여 줘.

Comment: Hello, please don't forget to click the Checkmark next to the answer you are selecting as "the answer".  Hey, you'll even be given two rep points for doing so, how cool is that?

Answer (score 8):

Okay, firstly, *you* can't say *you*.  Should you have to say *you*, you can't use 너.  That's pretty rude.

So, then, just leave the *you* out and let's go on.  There are few variants I recommend.

> 제가 할게요 or 제가 하겠습니다 - *I will do it.*

The other one is more of the "favor" feel.

> 제가 해 드릴까요? - *Shall I do it for you?*

Or you could force the issue.

> 제가 해 드리겠습니다 - *I'm going to do it for you.*

Comment: 제가 할게요 is the standard spelling.

Comment: @mujjingun it's funny, i thought so too, but when i let my Korean wife check it she made me change it ;)

Comment: @webjuju Using 너 is ok within friends of the same or lower age and will not be rude. But outside that relationship will def be rude

Comment: @supercoolhandsomegelboy the OP began with "저는" and ended with "요". one of these things is not like the other, and **너** is *it*.

Comment: @webjuju didn't realize you are referring to OP's ex. sentence, haha

Comment: @supercoolhandsomegelboy 제가 신경을 안 쓸게요!

Answer (score 3):

WEBjuju explained it well on a polite level. Casually, when speaking friend-to-friend, you can say equivalently:

> 내가 할게, 내가 해 줄게. - *I will do it, I will do it for you/him/her.*
>
> 내가 해 줄까? - *Shall I do it for you/him/her?*
>
> 내가 해 줄거야. - *I'm going to do it for you/him/her.*

Comment: right right! i followed the "저는" and "요" the OP was using, but it's good to point out the 반말 version, too! +1